# selecting from either of two columns in SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, if-statement

In SQL Server 2008R2 I have two tables, `CONFIG_DATA` and `CNA_LIST`:

`CONFIG_DATA` has two fields:

```
ID [varchar(20)]    Address [int]
01                  141516  
02                  132132
```

`CNA_LIST` has three fields:

```
Address [int]  IP1 [varchar(20)]   IP2 [varchar(20)]
141516         1.2.3.4             (null)
132132         (null)              2.3.4.5
```

These are field devices that have one or two IP addresses, in the `IP1` or `IP2` field (can be either, or both).

I would like to list the `CONFIG_DATA` table with `IP1` from the `CNA_LIST` table, and if it's `NULL`, the `IP2`.

The `Address` field links the two tables.

this would work fine:

```
select a.ID, a.Address, b.IP1
from CONFIG_DATA a, CNA_LIST b where a.Address = b.Address
```

but if `IP1` is `null` I need `IP2`, with this column listed as `"IP"`:

I've tried `IF(b.IP1 <> '')b.IP1 ELSE b.IP2` but the syntax checker complains.

Comment: `CASE WHEN <evaluation_1> THEN <value_1> WHEN <evaluation_2> THEN <value_2> ... ELSE <value_n> END AS <column_name>`

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use either the [isnull()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) or [coalesce()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) functions to do this:

```
select a.ID, a.Address, isnull(b.IP1, b.IP2) as "IP"
from CONFIG_DATA a
inner join CNA_LIST b on a.Address = b.Address
```

I also rewrote your query to use explicit joins instead of the older implicit join syntax.

`isnull()` takes two arguments (*check, replacement*) and returns the second if the first is `NULL`. 

`coalesce()` works almost the same way but can take more than two arguments and returns the first non-`NULL` argument or `NULL` if all arguments are `NULL`.

There's also a third way that doesn't rely on the build-in function, which is ti use the [case](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) expression like this: `case when b.IP1 is not null then b.IP1 else b.IP2 end`

Comment: I would suggest adding nullif() to the two fields to account for blanks unless you are absolutely sure that missing values are going to be NULL.   isnull(nullif(b.IP1,''),nullif(b.IP2))